# Eclipse - How to remove the Project Explorer tab

Tags: eclipse

I accidentally pressed something which created an hierarchy view tab top of the class view as presented below:

[image]

I'd like to know how to remove it.

Comment: Try going to Window/Perspective/Reset Perspective from the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for that type of hierarchy format is a breadcrumb. You can disable it with the following:

Right click on it and select Hide Breadcrumb